# Why do we need to provide an .webm file extension inside <video> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, video, cross-browser

I need to show some Videos on the browser. Targeted browsers are IE8-above, firefox and chrome. 
After some goggling I found that, http://v4e.thewikies.com/ can used to generate video tags with fall-back option.

So I generated this tag,

```
<video controls="controls" width="640" height="360">
        <source src="http://localhost/abc.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="http://localhost/abc.webm" type="video/webm" />

        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://flashfox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/flashfox.swf" width="640" height="360">
            <param name="movie" value="http://flashfox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/flashfox.swf" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="flashVars" value="controls=true&amp;src=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fabc.mp4" />
            <span title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below">Big Buck Bunny</span>
        </object>
    </video>
```

From this tag, what I understood is , our browser will use html5 video tag if its supported else it will fallback to use object tag.

But why we also need to provide .webm format for the same video i.e

`<source src="http://localhost/abc.webm" type="video/webm" />`

Is there any specific cases where mp4 does not works but .webm files works fine?

Answer (score 0):

Video support across platforms and browsers is very fragmented and also constantly changing - the simple answer to your question is that you have understood correctly and there are indeed cases where mp4 will not be supported and webm will be.

For instance at the time of writing, Firefox only provides support conditionally (the condition being that a third party decoder is available), and mp4 files with a 'high' profile will not run on some low spec mobile devices. The mp4 format has quite a few patents, not all of which are free licensed - this is behind some of the issues.

There are some useful resources for seeing what is supported - as it keeps changing it is worth checking these when you are building your service/sit:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=webm

Comment: All modern browsers support mp4 now. There is much less support for webm. - https://caniuse.com/#search=mp4